# Solution in integers to $2^n+n=3^m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

How to find all positive integers $m,n$ such that $2^n+n=3^m$ ?

We have by inspection $(m,n)=(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$

And there are no more for m and n both less then $100$.

Comment: By analyzing residues modulo 6 you can tell that if n>0, then $n\cong 1 mod 6$. Maybe something in that direction could help?

Comment: @mother_to_5: Where did you find this problem? Is it a contest problem, or did you propose yourself. Such information can be helpful for users.

Comment: I proposed the problem myself. I have some related questions too, what is the density of numbers of the form x^m-y^n, for given x and y?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no other solutions for n<1000.

Comment: nor for n<59000.

Comment: There are no solutions with $n=6\,k+1$, $k\le10^6$.

Comment: There are no solutions for $n < 10^9.$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0512006v4.pdf) Lemma 2.2 gives that if $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ then
$$
\left|\log_3 2-\frac{p}{q}\right|\ge \frac{1}{1200 q^{14.3}}
$$
limiting how closely $\log_3 2$ can be approximated by rationals.
It then follows that if $m\log 3 = n\log 2 + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ then $\epsilon\ge \frac{\log 3}{1200 n^{14}}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
3^m & > 2^n (1+\epsilon) \\
& = 2^n + \frac{2^n \log 3}{1200 n^{14}}
\end{align}
$$
The second term is greater than $n$ for $n>112$, and a computer check also excludes $2\le n\le 112$, so there are no other solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Not a complete answer but some information about possible solutions $n, m$ can be deduced.  Suppose that $n, m > 0$ and write

$$ m = \frac{\log(2^n + n)}{\log(3)}.
$$

Since $\log(x + y) < \log(x) + y/x$ for all real $x, y > 0$ this implies that

$$
\frac{\log(2^n)}{\log(3)} < m < \frac{\log(2^n)}{\log(3)} + \frac{n}{2^n \log(3)}
$$

and therefore that

$$
0 < \frac{m}{n} - \frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)} < \frac{1}{2^n \log(3)}.
$$

So $\tfrac{m}{n}$ is very close to $\tfrac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}$.  So close in fact that it must appear as an upper bound in its continued fraction expansion.  This at least makes it a bit simpler to scan for possible solutions.